# I am trying to select PDF file on button click but I am getting an error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to select PDF file on button click but I'm getting following message on samsung device :

> all apps associated with this action have been turned off blocked or
>   are not installed.

```
private void selectPDFFiles(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"select PDF "), 1);
}
```

Comment: Please post only code that causes the error. The worst thing is that you did not even tell which code block causes the error. Should we guess?

Comment: I don't see any error message in logcat. @blackapps

Comment: Can be. But i did not ask for that. Please reread my comment and then remove the irrelevant code. Leave the code that gives you the message. You start twice an activity. And you did not tell at which start you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
private void selectPDFFiles(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 555);
}
```

And you can get file in activity result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 555:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Update**

Also try below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, 555);
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: getting error: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=application/pdf }

Comment: You are using fragment or activity?

Comment: I am using activity.

Comment: `String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();` That will not work. You can not use the File class on a content scheme. Look at the values of uri.toString() and myFile.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: @blackapps It's only for sample,You can get as your wise.